# How do I check if an app is installed on iOS?

Tags: ios

I can use:

```objective-c
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"xxxx"];
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
}
```

I know can set other app schema in Info.plist file can check but it has a 50 count limit. Is there any way I can check other app install status where no configuration is required?

Comment: Why do you need to know if more than 50 specific apps are installed? What problem are you actually trying to solve? Please update your question with more details.

Comment: The url query list and limit was added specifically to prevent apps from inventorying all the apps that a user has installed

Comment: Because some business services need to check and（guide download page or help users open the specified app）,we can get their specific schema,but more than 50